# PHP fwrite always returns the number of bytes to be written even if the file doesn't exist, is this expected behaviour?

Tags: php, fwrite

I have the following example code

```
<?php
`echo test > /tmp/test.txt`;
$f=fopen("/tmp/test.txt","w+");
`rm /tmp/test.txt`;
var_dump(fwrite($f,"test"));
fclose($f);
file_get_contents("/tmp/test.txt");
```

Which creates a file, opens a pointer to it, removes the file then attempts to write to it. Now I would expect the fwrite to return false or 0 since no data will be written, however it produces the following output

```
int(4)

Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Stuff/tmp/test3 on line 7
```

So the fwrite apparently succeeds but the file_get_contents fails as expected.

Is it expected behaviour for the fwrite to return the number of bytes to be written? If so how can I test if the write was really successful?

This is with php 5.3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's returning `false` is that the file pointer is at the end of the file after `fwrite`...  That's what [`fgets`](https://www.php.net/fgets) is supposed to do when it reaches the end of the file (it returns `false` since there is no more data to get)...

What you need to do is add a [`fseek`](https://www.php.net/fseek) call before you call `fgets`:

```
var_dump(fwrite($f,"test"));
fseek($f, 0);
var_dump(fgets($f));
```

**Edit:** Now that I understand your question (and have looked at it):

Alright, so here's what's happening.  To understand, you must first know how Linux filesystems work.  The file's name is meaningless to the operating system.  All it does is point to the [`INODE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for the file.  The inode stores the data, etc.  It also stores a reference number to the number of [hard-links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to that file.  The file is only deleted when the reference number falls to 0.  I'm suspecting that opening a pointer to the file (using `fopen`, or other system calls) increases the reference count.

So basically, what that means is that when you ran `rm` on the file, it deleted the hard-link.  But since the file was still open, you could still access the inode through `fwrite` (hence why the write succeeded).  You couldn't access `/tmp/test.txt` since the hard link to that filename no longer existed.  So the file became a phantom file that is only accessible by the inode.  But as soon as you closed the file handle for that file (`fclose`, or by ending the script) the reference count fell to 0 and the inode was freed...

So the file does exist, it's just not accessible from the filename after you call `rm`...

That's just what I'm gathering by knowing what I know about the filesystems.  I'm not saying it's 100% accurate, but it should be a decent hypothesis...

Comment: I've altered the question to make it clearer, it's not about the fgets it's about fwrite reporting it writes 4 bytes to a file that doesn't exist, shouldn't fwrite return 0 or false?

Comment: +1 rewind($f) will also work (pertaining to original question).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, a pain but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If this is on a Linux (and possible other unix-like OSes) system, the reference to the file in the filesystem is deleted by `rm`, but the file itself still exists until all programs reading from/writing to it are closed.

This is due to how [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) work; all entries in the filesystem are hard links, [soft links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), or devices.

Comment: Incidentally, Windows will just throw an error if you try to delete a file while another process is reading from/writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should allow you to check whether it was a successful write.

```
 if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
 }
```

Comment: But the `var_dump` shows that `4` was returned, indicating that 4 bytes were written.  So that check wouldn't indicate an error in this case (not saying it's bad, just not applicable to this problem)...

Comment: It doesn't the var_dump shows the fwrite output as 4 which isn't false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first must save the file

```
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Closing the file is not the same as saving.  It does force a flush, but you don't have to close it to force the flush.  And considering that it's buffered you'd only need to flush to see the changes from another process.  Plus you could just use the [`fflush`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) command instead of closing and re-opening the file...

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some conditions, error handling e.g.

- check whether the file exists
- whether the file is writable
- whether the data was written to the file
- whether the data are readable

Comment: This is just example code, my question is regarding the fwrite is it expected behaviour for it to return that it wrote 4 bytes to a non existent file shouldn't it return 0 or false?